# How to read libsodium's scalar from integer/bytes or NTL:zz

Tags: implementation, libsodium

Hi I am new to lib sodium, may I ask that is it possible to get scalar of ristretto255 from integer/bytes or NTL:zz? 
Some thing as follows:

```
crypto_core_ristretto255_from_bytes(px, x); 
crypto_core_ristretto255_from_int(px, x); 
crypto_core_ristretto255_from_ntl(px, x);
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The byte representation of a scalar is just the scalar encoded as little endian.